# Many hold a master's degree

Tags: grammaticality

"Many of our employees hold a master's degree."

"Many of our employees hold master's degrees."

"Many of our employees hold masters' degrees."

Which of the above is the correct expression, assuming *none* of the employees have *more than one* master's degree? (You can either have 1 or none).

For me, I feel #1 sounds the most natural, but I'm not sure it is correct.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: This isn't a duplicate as the question isn't about whether or not you need an apostrophe at all (all three of my examples given have apostrophes in them)!

Comment: This is only a 'half-duplicate', namely as it concerns the apostrophe. However, the present question also asks about singular vs plural, which is not addressed at all in the [*Is there an apostrophe in a master's degree?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/is-there-an-apostrophe-in-a-masters-degree) question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm ruling out the third one as it just doesn't sound right!

I think with the second constraint given (*i.e they can either have one degree or none*), the first one seems appealing. 
The second one partly gives room for us to assume that they can either have one **or** two degrees.