# Masters or Master's (for my specific situation)

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, possessives, writing-advice

I'm going to apply for the statistics graduate school at UCSB. So is it okay to say I am the "*Applicant for UCSB Statistics Master*"? Or any suggestions about other forms, like "*UCSB Masters Applicant*" or "*UCSB Master's Applicant*"? (I can't distinguish which version is correct here!)

I have to be very cautious because it's the header of my personal statement like this picture is showing:

[image: image with text “Applicant for UCSB Statistics Master<TAB>MY FULL NAME<NEWLINE><NEWLINE><TAB>Personal Statement”]

---

Well, thanks for all the comments. By your guidance I see the standard form should be "*Applicant for Masters Degree in Statistics at UCSB*", but it is a little bit prolix using at the header. What if I omit the information about *Statistics*? Namely, is "*Applicant for Masters at UCSB*" or "*UCSB Masters Application*" okay?

Comment: "Masters" to mean "Master of Science" (or of some other discipline) is informal. I do not recommend using it here. The formal way is to name the degree, e.g. "Master of Science".

Comment: @Mike Graham So _Applicant for Master of Statistics Degree Course at UCSB_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't know what degrees UCSB offers in statistics and did not research it. They probably offer a Master of Science and may offer other degrees, such as Master of Arts. It would be quite unconventional for them to offer a Master of Statistics.

Comment: As for the best phrasing of the heading, it might depend on what it's supposed to accomplish. The recipients probably know they work for UCSB statistics department/sub-department. "Master of Science Application" might be a good choice. I don't know what the real goal is, though.

Comment: Their own [web page](https://www.pstat.ucsb.edu/graduate/ma) says "Our department offers a Masters Degree in Statistics", so you have a form to follow.

Comment: I've a BA and MA and took Natural Science: Chemistry! Naming can be traditional rather than modern-logical. //// So 'Masters Degree in Statistics' is obviously what _they_ use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the expected format is actually provided by the institution, as @kimchi lover unearths. "Masters Degree in Statistics" (plural attributive: no apostrophe /// not the "Master of Philosophy" format).

Comment: The general apostrophy-or-not question has already been addressed at [Is there an apostrophe in a masters degree?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/is-there-an-apostrophe-in-a-masters-degree).